# Spark 3.3.2 streaming/batch metrics in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, spark-structured-streaming

how to restrict spark to write spark metrics on single port & path?

I have tried to pull spark prometheus compatible metrics. The issue is I don't have any discovery services and in production cloud we are having dynamic spark IP/port for executors and workers.
How to provide the targets scrape configurations in Prometheus